# Get Photo_ID in PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, upload

How do i get the Photo_ID from an photo which my app uploaded with the PHP SDK Code:

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$img = '/tmp/mypic.png';
$photo = $facebook->api(‘/me/photos’, ‘POST’,
                        array( ‘source’ => ‘@’ . $img,
                               ‘message’ => ‘Photo uploaded via the PHP SDK!’
                       ));
```

Didnt see that it will give any response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response of a successful upload is the id of the photo, [example](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/):

```
{
   "id": "1001207389476"
}
```

So `$photo` should hold a similar value.

Comment: Thats is developer blindness. I imaged the most difficult ways, but didnt saw $photo! Thanks!